# Stop button to repet in loop

Tags: php, html

Is there any way to stop a button from submit button to stop looping in while loop?
it just looks terrible to have like 15 submit buttons insted of 1. whitout moving it from the from

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bestalning` WHERE lev=0
ORDER BY tid";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
echo "<div class='continer bg-vit table-rsponsive-sm '>";
echo "<table class='table'>";
echo    "<thead class='thead-dark'>";
echo       "<tr><th>Lev</th>";
echo           "<th>&nbsp;</th>";
echo           "<th>Artikelnr</th>";
echo           "<th>Antal</th>";
echo           "<th>Singnatur</th>";
echo           "<th>Önskad ankomst</th>";
echo           "<th>Skickad</th>";
echo       "</tr></thead><tbody>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<form method='POST' action='ID_change.php'>";
    echo "<td><input style='margin-right:5px;' name='levJA' type='checkbox' value='1'></td>";
    echo "<td><input style='margin-right:5px;' name='RowID' type='hidden' value='".$row['ID']."'></td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['artikelnr']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['antal']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['ovrigt']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Tid']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
    echo "<input class='btn btn-dark m-1' type='submit' value='submit'>;
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</tr>";

}



echo "</tbody></table>";
echo "</div>";
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: @Nick need it in the from other wise the ID in the hidden input becoms the higest in the table

Comment: Right... Just one submit button for many forms is not possible... A possible way may be to add a checkbox in all your forms and just one submit button... But, you have to add some javascript to handle the behaviour of your submit

Comment: Didn't notice you had multiple forms. As @Jean-LucAubert says, having only one submit button becomes a lot more complex.

Comment: @Jean-LucAubert to bad you just can't move the end form outside the loop to make it work.

Comment: @Nick i just hade an 3am type ide. What if you do so the checkbox is the submit button but still the checkbox #Fthebutton

Comment: @Jean-LucAubert join the #Fthebutton movement

Comment: If ever you put your submit button outside the loop, you can't submit a specific form! So, move form before the loop and /form after your loop, and the submit button too! Next you have to rename your fields too... and on the submission just check if checkbox are or not checked to make your business

Comment: @Jean-LucAubert my dude i fixed it i used som javascript thats submits the the form on change so i don't need any buttons

Comment: Another way... Good luck...

Comment: @Jean-LucAubert don't believe me just watch    onChange='this.form.submit()'

Comment: It's a correct way to manage your forms